# Not simplify an easy equation with "Simplify"

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I've a problem with the function Simplify. I've this equations `x^2 + 2 x + 1 == 0` and `4 x^2 == 0`. If I use Simplify, it returns `1 + x == 0` and `x == 0`. How I can force Simplify to not simplify this type of equations? I've to use Simplify in a function and I need it for other cases.

Thanks

Comment: The question is not clear. A good idea would be to show the expression with `Simplify` to let us see what is it that you are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ExcludeForms` option described in the [Simplify documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html).

For example,

```
Simplify[{x^2 + 2 x + 1 == 0, 4 x^2 == 0}, ExcludedForms -> {0}]

(* returns {(x + 1)^2 == 0, 4 x^2 == 0} *)
```

Alternatively,

```
Simplify[{x^2 + 2 x + 1 == 0, 4 x^2 == 0}, ExcludedForms -> {x^2, 0}]

(* returns {1 + 2 x + x^2 == 0, 4 x^2 == 0} *)
```

The actual forms to exclude will depend a bit on what your other expressions look like, but you can find a few more general pattern examples in the [ExcludedForms documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExcludedForms.html).

Comment: And if I have `3 (2 - 6 x) == 9 (3 - 2 x) - 21`, how I force Simplify to not show  `True` but simply `0 == 0`?

Comment: @RossFe, Sorry but I am not sure I understand the question. Is x define to a set value? Or do you want both the constants and x variable dominate from both sides? Out of curiosity, why do you prefer 0==0 over True?